# Attribute bind-value is not set in iron-input when initiated

Tags: data-binding, polymer-1.0

Here's a pattern I try to do with Polymer:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html" />

<dom-module id="my-entity">
    <template>

        <iron-ajax auto url="{{urlGet}}" handle-as="json" last-response="{{entity}}"></iron-ajax>
        <iron-ajax id="updateEntityCall" url="{{urlUpdate}}" handle-as="json" on-response="handleUpdateResponse"></iron-ajax>

        <div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{entityName}}" value="{{entity.name}}" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button on-click="saveEntity">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer(
            {
                is: "my-entity",
                properties: {
                    entityid: {
                        notify: true
                    },
                    entityName: {
                        notify: true
                    }
                    urlGet: {
                        computed: 'getUrlGet(entityid)'
                    },
                    urlTemplate: {
                        computed: 'getUrlUpdate(entityid, entityName)'
                    },
                },
                getUrlGet: function (entityId) {
                    return ['/path/to/get', entityId].join('/');
                },
                getUrlUpdate: function (entityId, entityName) {
                    return ['/path/to/update', entityId, entityName].join('/');
                },
                saveEntity: function (e, detail, sender) {
                    this.$.updateEntityCall.generateRequest();
                }
            }
        );
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I first create a `iron-ajax` that will get some data from an entity. This will be printed in a `iron-input` element so a person will be able to update this entity.

The `iron-ajax` is bound to a `{{entity}}` variable that is used by the `value` in the `iron-input` element (`entity.name`). I have created a property called `entityName` that will be bound at the `bind-value` attribute of this same `iron-input`.

Once someone has made the change, the goal is that he/she clicks on the `button` that calls the function `saveEntity`, that basically call the other `iron-ajax` element.

There is no problem with this code when someone actually change the value of the `iron-input`. **The problem appear when the user don't change the value and click the button. It sends nothing, like if `entityName` is not set.**

This is a simple example, in my use-case I have 3 fields and 2 of them can have "empty strings" as valid value.

Comment: As far as I can see, you haven't declared the property `entity`, which may be the issue here, because your `iron-input` doesn't know what `entity` is and therefore never changes. Try adding: `entity: {type: Object, notify: true}`

Comment: Adding the `entity` attribute didn't trigger the `entityName` to be initiated (it worked even if it wasn't in my properties). I worked around this by setting a `on-response` attribute that manage the affectation manually.